# CSS style is not displayed when landing on page through HTML anchor tag, how do I "restore" it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor

I have an index.html page where through an anchor tag the user can go to the contact.html page. On the contact.html page I also have some anchor tags that should bring the user back to a specific section of the index.html page. It works, but once we are back into the index.html it doesn't show the styling. How can I fix this? You can see the hrefs of the contact.html here below:

```
    <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="/index.html/#footer">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/index.html/#pricing">Pricing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/index.html/#cta">Download</a>
    </li>
```

Thank you.

---

I'll add some more information as requested - also now when I am clicking on the navbar links in the contact.html page, instead of the "unstyled" index page this error pops up:
Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, stat '/home/mp/code/m-p/tflix/tflix-start/index.html/'

Anyway some more snippets of CSS and HTML code:

Bootstrap navbar in contact.html

```
<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">tinflix</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs- 
     toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria- 
     controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria- 
     label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="/index.html/#footer">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/index.html/#pricing">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/index.html/#cta">Download</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

</body>
```

In index.html, the page is divided up in sections with ids for example:

```
<section id="pricing">
  <h1 class="big-white-header"> This is the pricing section </h1>
</section>
```

As for the CSS, as an example:

```
  body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
  }
  h1, h2, h3, h5 {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .big-white-header {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }
```

Please tell me if more info is needed, thank you for your help!

---

Solved it by removing the slashes from the nav-link hrefs! Thank you for everyone that helped

Comment: That code sample is insufficient please edit the question with more details - specifically regarding the css/styles that are missing, note also that it doesn’t matter how you arrive, the url when it works and when it doesn’t is the important part. That said: `href="/index.html/` seems very likely to be using relative paths for assets and this is changing the “directory”. Look (using browser tools) at the requested path for the css file, that 404 needs addressing.

Comment: Please provide a code sample for css style. If you can add snippet to your question, it will be helpful.

Comment: Please add more code snippets of your HTML files, and CSS style sheets so we can reproduce your issues and provide you with a solution.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but could you elaborate on this: "That said: href="/index.html/ seems very likely to be using relative paths for assets and this is changing the “directory”." What is meant for "relative paths for assets"? Thank you

Comment: `http://host.com/assets/res.anything` is an absolute url .. `/assets/res` , `./path/page.html` , `../path2/page.html` are relative urls. The way a relative url gets translated to an absolute url depends on the page asking for them (not the js, not the css... the html) .. I suggest you to look for that topic on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Solution - Remove the slashes from the href links of nav items like so:

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="index.html#footer">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html#pricing">Pricing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html#cta">Download</a>
    </li>
```

Why exactly it works like this I still don't know, but it's solved.